# Where is the Extensionality of predicates axiom Coq

Tags: coq

The [Coq FAQ](https://coq.inria.fr/faq#htoc37) says that the axiom:

```
Extensionality of predicates: ∀ P Q:A→ Prop, (∀ x, P(x) ↔ Q(x)) → P=Q
```

Is consistent with Coq. In what library is this asserted? It's not in Logic, as the section implies, nor is it in Classical.

Comment: BTW, IMHO a more interesting question is what is the use case you have in mind for this very strong axiom.

Comment: @ejgallego I'm trying to prove that equivalence classes are disjoint. I'm pretty sure there's a constructive way to do it, but I'm more interested in proving things within standard logic than trying to force the proofs into constructive logic.

Frankly, while I understand the desire for minimality of axioms, I think that  for practical theorem proving, excluded middle, functional extensionality, and even extensionality of predicates are often very useful.

Comment: @ejgallego Kinda like using ST in Haskell. Often, slightly departing from the principle of the language is what makes it practical.

Comment: thanks for the comment! I must however differ a bit on the "departing from the principle of the language is what makes it practical", IMHO I've seen few benefits in Coq proofs come by using axioms (and often more trouble than gain); usually the axiom remedies the symptom, not the root cause of the inefficiency in the proof itself (a bad choice of representation is an often seen pitfall that no axiom will solve by itself).

Comment: @ejgallego that may be so, but I think that for people who want to quickly formalize proofs that are simple on paper, being able to, for example, `destruct (classic P)` is useful. Mostly because this kind of proof by case analysis is part of any high school or undergraduate introduction to logic. I personally see no reason to make life harder for myself when I'm trying to prove something, as long as I don't introduce inconsistencies.

Comment: @ejgallego In this case, introducing predicate extensionality was probably not the best way to go about my proof, I will admit.

Comment: Yeah that was a bit of my point, for instance, when I see programmers doing `destruct (classic P)` is almost surely a bad sign; most of the time `P` should be a decidable type by construction; but using the axiom lets you get away with the bad definition; however you will surely pay the price in other parts of your proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Extensionality_Ensembles` from the `Ensembles` library is equivalent to the axiom you posted.

Answer (score 3):

I think the axiom is not declared in the current standard library; it is a pretty strong one (as you can see in `ClassicalFacts.v`) so you need to declare it yourself. Your particular case follows from it + function extensionality I think:

```
Require Import ClassicalFacts.
Require Import FunctionalExtensionality.

Axiom pe : prop_extensionality.

Lemma pred_extensionality A (P Q : A -> Prop) :
  (forall x, P x <-> Q x) -> P = Q.
Proof. now intros H; apply functional_extensionality; intros x; apply pe. Qed.
```

Comment: OK thanks! I ended up doing something similar, but I was wondering if there was a library I could import

Comment: @k_g Just a remark: in [`Logic.Diaconescu`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Diaconescu.html) we have the `PredicateExtensionality` axiom defined, but for `bool -> Prop` predicates.